# Can a .vm(velocity template) file included inside an HTML fILE IN Spring

Tags: java, html, spring, spring-mvc, velocity

Is there any way to include an .vm file inside the .HTML file and return the .HTML file as the view in spring, I have seen example where the whole HTML changed to .vm and used as view. But I would like only one page to be changed as .vm with all other files still uses .HTML extension, is this possible in spring, could you please suggest

Regards
Vivek

Comment: "Is there any way to include an .vm file inside the .HTML" Nope because vm files need processing before they are used. "I would like only one page to be changed as .vm with all other files still uses .HTML extension" You have to use [two separate view resolvers](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-viewresolver-chaining) for that

Comment: thank you for your reply